# mysql query to get result coming in next 2 months

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get result which is coming in next 2 months i am using following query(release date format is normal in database **8 March 2013**)

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y')-now()<2months) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y') DESC LIMIT 20
```

i know 2 months will not work ... so how will this work in mysql... thx ... other way i am trying is

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y')-now()<5184000000) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y') DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx guys i found the ans (sir ji helped me ;) )

```
"SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE (TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y'))-TO_DAYS(NOW())<60 && TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y'))-TO_DAYS(NOW())>0) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y') LIMIT 20"
```

this way i we can limit the start and end date ... from now().. hope will help

Answer (score 0):

This query may provide you output:

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Let me know the solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE DATE_SUB(CURRDATE(),(STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y')) <60 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y') DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should help

```
SELECT * FROM `imdb` WHERE ( DATE_SUB(`release`, INTERVAL 2 MONTH) < now()) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`release`, '%e %M %Y') DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName ( SELECT MONTH(datefieldName) AS m , DAY(datefiled) As d FROM tableName) AS tmp ORDER BY (m,d) < ( MONTH(CURDATE()), DAY(CURDATE()) ), m , d limit 0,20";
```

Hope it will useful for you!